# Running MonkeyTalk script with ANT on Macosx

Tags: ios, testing, ant, monkey

I'm try to run a MonkeyTalk script for my iOS app from command line. The script is successfully running in the MonkeyTalkIDE and get executed on the Simulator.

I have *build.xml* and *Monkey-tal.jar* files in the same directory of *test.mt*

The build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TEST3" xmlns:monkeytalk="antlib:com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.ant">
  <target name="myScript">
    <monkeytalk:run agent="iOS" script="test.mt" />
  </target>
</project>
```

I'm running the command:

```
 ant -lib monkeytalk-ant.jar test.mt
```

and I get the error message:

```
MacBook-Pro-2948:TEST3 Developer$ ant -lib monkeytalk-ant.jar test.mt 
Buildfile: /Users/Developer/Downloads/monkeytalk 2/MonkeyTalkIDE/MonkeyTalkIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/workspace/TEST3/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "test.mt" does not exist in the project "TEST3".
```

Total time: 0 seconds

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the way I was launching the script.

```
ant -lib monkeytalk-ant.jar myScript
```